# Store data in web api asp.net server till user logout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

After user selection the connection should be store somewhere not at frontend because it contains database server id and password 
The data which will be needed to generate connection string which is required by entity framework to connect.

Backend: WEB API 2 ASP.NET

Frontend: HTML,AngularJS

My question is that how i do store in web server till user logout [Note: for each user the data/connection will be unique] .

That data is confidential, so it cannot be store at browser.

Project structure.
[image]

Comment: [Session state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) would be my guess without knowing anything else.

Comment: @Igor I think [ASP.NET Profile Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) seems more promising for this implementation. I am adding a image for better understanding. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api
If you want to use IdentityFramewok if not, SessionState can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MemoryCache**

> To set

```
MemoryCache memoryCache =  MemoryCache.Default;
string key = "keyName", data = "data"; int addDuration = 10;
memoryCache.Add(key, data, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(addDuration));
```

> To get

```
memoryCache[key];
```

> To update

```
memoryCache[key] = "some data";
```